# Setting a value from function parameter const string(&)

Tags: c++

Very noobish, simple question, which hopefully has an easy answer. My issue basically comes down to a single line of code on a function parameter that is:

```
void className::read(const string &)
{
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open(fname);
  /* ...function code */
  fin.close()
}
```

The input is established in main as a string, fname (i.e. `object.read(fname)`). 
When I do this, it tells me that fname has not been declared in this scope. My question, thus,  is how to use fname, the input, as the file name in fin.open().
Thanks to everyone who has already helped and sorry for the poor explanation of the issue earlier.

Comment: You mean like `std::string str = fname;` or `std::string str; ... str = fname;?` That's what it sounds like, but it feels like there's more to it than that.

Comment: To make this clearer, perhaps you could add the relevant parts of your `main()` function as well, and show how you call `className::read()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fname refers to the function parameter well you can because it has a const modifier. So you'd have to remove the const modifier. Once that is done it's like assigning to any other variable.

If however you meant use the value of fname within the function well that's even simpler, you just create a new variable and assign it:

```
std::string newVariable = fname;
```

Comment: That's not an option unfortunately. Let me be a little more specific. I have to grab the value fname and use it for ifstreamObject.open(fname). I may not actually need to set a string within the function equal to fname, but I do need to somehow call fname from memory. Hope that helps, should have been more specific earlier.

Comment: @zetametroid, That call works fine in C++11. In C++03, you need `.open(fname.c_str());`

Comment: Your question is/was somewhat misleading. You can just use the variable directly in the function, if you need to modify it make a local copy (I edited my answer with and example).

Comment: Yes, I think I was going about the problem wrong and there wasn't enough info, sorry about that, editing to correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I might be oversimplifying this, but is this what you want? A named parameter of `fname`?

```
void className::read(const string& fname)
{
  printf(fname.c_str()); // Do what you want with the string.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking whether you can modify `fname` within the function? If that's what you want you need to modify the signature of the `read` function to take a non-const reference.

```
void className::read( string& fname )
{
  fname = "something else";  // this change is visible even after the 
                             // function returns
}
```

Or are you asking how to create a local string that is a copy of `fname`?

```
void className::read( const string& fname )
{
  std::string local = fname;  // local contains a copy of fname
}
```